# Trouble starting Primefaces poll and kicking off method

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

My main form has a Primefaces poll with a message that I want to update with "in progress" or "completed."  My menu item opens up a dialog where I allow the user to confirm the action.  If yes, I want to start the poll, call the server method, and immediately close the dialog (because the method takes a while and we don't need to wait.)

If I start the poll in the same button that opens the dialog, it works.  If I start the poll in the button on my dialog, what happens is that the server method gets called but the poll does not start until the method is completed.  I used 'onclick' instead of 'oncomplete', but it's not helping.  I can tell because the poll listener method only gets invokes when the main method is finished. I've looked through @BalusC posts about order of actions, etc., but I know I'm missing something simple here.

Sample code:

(myForm)

```
<p:poll widgetVar="statusPoll" interval="1" autoStart="false" update="myStatus"  
    listener="#{bean.pollListener}"  
stop="#{bean.pollStopped}"/>  
<h:outputText id="myStatus" value="#{bean.status}"/>

<p:menuitem value="Start job" onclick="PF('jobModal').show();">
```

(jobModal)
...

```
<p:commandButton value="Run the job"
    action="#{bean.runMethod}"
    onclick="PF('statusPoll').start();PF('jobModal').hide();"/>
```

Comment: What about using `onstart`?

Comment: I thought onclick is the first to execute? But maybe this will be cleaner if I start the poll from the menunitem,  and then if the user does not want to proceed on the dialog, I can stop it.

Comment: I used `async="true"` on the p:poll and it worked out for my similar problem.